# Accessing values in a sub-dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Hello I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dictionary = {'John': {'car':12, 'house':10, 'boat':3},
              'Mike': {'car':5, 'house':4, 'boat':6}}
```

I want to gain access and extract the keys within the sub-dictionary and assign them to variables like this:

```
cars_total = dictionary['car']
house_total = dictionary['house']
boat_total = dictionary['boat']
```

Now, when I run the variables above I get a 'Key Error'. It is understandable because I need to first access the outer dictionary. I would appreciate if someone gave a helping hand on how to access keys and the values within the sub-dictionary as those are the values I want to use.

Also i would like to do create a new key, this may not be right but something on these lines:

```
    car = dictionary['car']
    house = dictionary['house']
    boat = dictionary['boat']

dictionary['total_assets'] = car + house + boat
```

I want to be able to access all those keys in the dictionary and create a new key. The outer keys such as "John' and 'Mike' should both contain the newly made key at the end.
I know this throws an error but it will give you an idea on what I want to achieve. Thanks for the help

Comment: .... `dictionary['John']['car']`? But I can only surmise your re trying to *sum* those values for all the keys in the outer dictionary?

Comment: is there anyway to do it via using a loop ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Are the internal keys always available?

Comment: Do what? You haven't specified anything except how to *access* a value

Comment: ok thanks, what if I there is a case I do not want the total and I just want the key in the inner dictionary and assign it to a variable , how do I do that? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DeepakM which inner dictionary, there are *two*...

Comment: I want to get access to the keys such as 'car', 'boat' and 'house' and assign them to variables respectively @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DeepakM They are already assigned variables... for what purpose?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. You should elaborate with examples in the question...

Comment: @DeepakM This doesn't clarify anything at all. Instead of using syntax that you *know doesn't work* why can't you just post your expected output??

Comment: OK to make it simple i want to create a new key called 'total_assets' with the sum of the other keys. I want the 'total_asset' key to be in both 'John and 'Mike' dictionary. Get it now? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Why don't you **just write the result you want**

Comment: @DeepakM see my answer. This was quite the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks! that's what I wanted to know !@TemporalWolf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sum the total assets for each person and add it as a new key:

```
for person in dictionary:
    dictionary[person]['total_assets'] = sum(dictionary[person].values())
```

which will result in:

```
dictionary = {'John': {'car':12, 'house':10, 'boat':3, 'total_assets':25},
              'Mike': {'car':5, 'house':4, 'boat':6, 'total_assets':15}}
```

Comment: upvoted for finally figuring out what the OP was looking for.

Comment: sorry it was difficult to explain but thanks for the help all the same! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DeepakM review [ask] and [mcve] so next time it will be clearer.

Comment: @TemporalWolf out of curiosity. If I wanted 'total_assets' to only contain the sum of 'car' and 'house'. How would that work?

Comment: `sum(value for (key, value) in dictionary[person].items() if key != 'boat')`

Comment: Ah thanks, what if it was a case with a larger dictionary with much more values? Would this work                     sum(value for (key, value) in dictionary[person].items() if keys = 'car' ,'house ')  ?@TemporalWolf

Comment: @DeepakM `if key in ['car', 'house']` if you want to make a list of included values

Answer (score 6):

I would just use a `Counter` object to get the totals:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> totals = Counter()
>>> for v in dictionary.values():
...     totals.update(v)
...
>>> totals
Counter({'car': 17, 'house': 14, 'boat': 9})
>>> totals['car']
17
>>> totals['house']
14
>>>
```

This has the added benefit of working nicely even if the keys aren't always present.

If you want the total assets, you can then simply sum the values:

```
>>> totals['total_assets'] = sum(totals.values())
>>> totals
Counter({'total_assets': 40, 'car': 17, 'house': 14, 'boat': 9})
>>>
```

Comment: Counter really comes in handy here... :D

Comment: @repzero yeah, `Counter` is very handy quite often.

Comment: As originally asked, this was the best solution. And additional rep for massaging his real question out of him

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary` doens't have a key `car`, as you've seen. But `dictionary['John']` does.

```
$ >>> dictionary['John']
{'car': 12, 'boat': 3, 'house': 10}
>>> dictionary['John']['car']
12
>>>
```

The value associated with each key in `dictionary` is, itself, another dictionary, which you index separately. There is no single object that contains, e.g., the `car` value for each subdictionary; you have to iterate
over each value.

```
# Iterate over the dictionary once per aggregate
cars_total = sum(d['car'] for d in dictionary.values())
house_total = sum(d['house'] for d in dictionary.values())
boat_total = sum(d['boat'] for d in dictionary.values())
```

or

```
# Iterate over the dictionary once total
cars_total = 0
house_total = 0
boat_total = 0
for d in dictionary.values():
    cars_total += d['car']
    house_total += d['house']
    boat_total += d['boat']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'John': {'car':12, 'house':10, 'boat':3},'Mike': {'car':5, 'house':4, 'boat':6}}
total_cars=sum([dictionary[x]['car'] for x in dictionary ])
total_house=sum([dictionary[x]['house'] for x in dictionary ])
total_boats=sum([dictionary[x]['boat'] for x in dictionary ])
print(total_cars)
print(total_house)
print(total_boats)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample iteration method:

```
from collections import defaultdict
totals = defaultdict(int)
for person in dictionary:
    for element in dictionary[person]:
        totals[element] += dictionary[person][element]

print(totals)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'car': 17, 'boat': 9, 'house': 14})
```